# Tabela sendo renderizada pelo Firefox com diferentes espessuras de bordas

Tags: html, css, firefox, tabela-html, css-border

Estou com um problema especificamente para tabelas renderizadas no firefox. Eu preciso utilizar a propriedade border-collapse em minhas tabelas para juntar a borda das células. Porém quando o firefox renderiza a tabela, as bordas ficam com espessuras diferentes conforme a figura abaixo.

OBS: Este problema não ocorre no Chrome.

Imagem da tabela renderizada. Veja que as linhas destacadas de vermelho estão mais grossas:
[image]

Código HTML e CSS da tabela:

```
//HTML
<div id="divTabela">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" border="1" name="tabelainfo" id="tabelainfo" class="bordasimples">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="titulotabela">
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Data Inicial</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Data Final</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Distribuidor</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Agendar</th>
                <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Ver Detalhes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="corpotabela">
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div title="Ver Detalhes"><a href="#"><div></div></a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="corpotabela"><td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####/td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1">####</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1" rowspan="1"><div title="Ver Detalhes"><a href="#"><div></div></a></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>



//CSS
table.bordasimples {border-collapse: collapse;}
table.bordasimples tr td {border:1px solid;}
table.bordasimples tr th {border:1px solid;}

#tabelainfo {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-align: justify;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #083c06;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4A6w2/1/embedded/result/) aqui aparece perfeito.

Comment: Isso parece mais um problema de *zoom* ou então de suavização aplicada sobre os gráficos.

Comment: Aplique um zoom e veja se altera alguma coisa.

Comment: Olá @MiguelAngelo, eu testei o seu jsfiddle no firefox e o problema persistiu. Porém no chrome está tudo ok.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito: deve ser específico da versão que você está usando então. Se for isso, não me preocuparia, pois no caso seria um bug de uma versão específica.

Comment: Consegui resolver tratando apenas o código CSS da seguinte forma:

    table.bordasimples {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border:1px solid #D2DDD4;
    }
    table.bordasimples tr td {border:1px solid #D2DDD4;}
    table.bordasimples tr th {border:1px solid #D2DDD4;}

Ou seja, substituí o border-collapse pelo border-spacing e o problema foi resolvido. A nova borda ficou um pouco mais escura, então para tratar este problema, substituí as cores das bordas.

Muito obrigado pelas sugestões de todos vocês, foram elas que me fizeram pensar diferente e resolver este problema.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito: Você poderia adicionar o seu comentário anterior como resposta? Assim, se outras possoas tiverem o mesmo problema, fica fácil para elas acharem onde está a solução. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver tratando apenas o código CSS da seguinte forma:

```
table.bordasimples {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border:1px solid #D2DDD4;
}
table.bordasimples tr td {border:1px solid #D2DDD4;}
table.bordasimples tr th {border:1px solid #D2DDD4;}
```

Ou seja, substituí o border-collapse pelo border-spacing e o problema foi resolvido. A nova borda ficou um pouco mais escura, então para tratar este problema, substituí as cores das bordas.

Muito obrigado pelas sugestões de todos vocês, foram elas que me fizeram pensar diferente e resolver este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Qual versão do seu firefox ? com a versão 28.0 funcionou o código que você postou perfeito, não deu para simular.

Mas o que eu acho que pode ser o problema seria o seu style.
Pois você faz o desenho da borda no topo e depois embaixo, assim fica sempre com 2 linhas, em alguns casos isso pode apresentar com pequena diferença.

Tente deixar o seu style assim:

```
#tabelainfo {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-align: justify;
    border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #083c06;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: A versão do meu firefox é a 28, porém já testei em outras versões anteriores e o problema persiste.

Comment: infelizmente com o código que você postou não apresenta defeitos. porém quando estou fazendo um report no C# costumo colocar borda somente a linha de baixo..pq isso tb costuma acontecer lá.